# Ограничить картинку в css по одному габариту

Tags: css

Застрял на простейшем, вроде, вопросе: ограничить картинку по большему габариту с сохранением пропорций. То есть чтобы картинка не выходила, скажем, за габарит 600px (по ширине или высоте). Если задавать `max-widht:600px`, `max-height:600px`, ломается пропорция изображения. Пробовал через различные варианты с `vmin` и `vmax`, через `min(...)` и `clamp(...)` - победить не смог

Comment: `object-fit` не помогло?

Comment: Да, с ним в итоге и сделал. Долго тупил, с ``cover``, пока не изменил на: `contain`` и немного поколдовал с тонкими настройками позиции и полей

Answer (score 0):

Что если использовать картинку как `background-image` с `background-size: contain`?

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper pict"></div>
  </body>
</html>


.wrapper {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
}
.pict {
   background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fw800/background/20230610/pngtree-picture-of-a-blue-bird-on-a-black-background-image_2937385.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге сделал через `object-fit`. Долго тупил, с `cover`, пока не изменил на `contain` и немного поколдовал с тонкими настройками позиции и полей